# Using SQL Function/Procedure to get last Financial year date range (July last year to June this Year)

Tags: mysql, sql

[result query should look like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su9WK.png) ]I'm trying to work out a way to use functions on mysql workbench, my query here is to get financial year(July last year to June this year) based on the given date as parameter
Here is my function to get an idea

```
create function GetFIYear(@parm varchar(50)) RETURNS VARCHAR
  AS
  BEGIN
  DECLARE @FIYear VARCHAR(20)
  SELECT FIYear = (CASE WHEN (MONTH(GETDATE()))
  <= 7 THEN convert(varchar(4), YEAR(GETDATE())-1) + '-' + convert(varchar(4), YEAR(GETDATE())%100)
  ELSE convert(varchar(4),YEAR(GETDATE()))+ '-' + convert(varchar(4),(YEAR(GETDATE())%100)+1)END)
  
return @FIYear
END
```

@PARM is a parameter , GETDATE() can be replaced with the parameter date during function call..

I would then like to use SELECT statement to execute the query(not identical to the one below)

```
select Title,
GetFIYear(@date_parameter) 
from [table];
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: my question is to get Financial year date fields for every row in the table, for instance, something similar to '2020-21' for dates ranging between July 2020 to June 2021

Comment: What MySQL version? Please run `SELECT version();` to check.

Comment: should `@PARM` be a date type?

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: @FanoFN  '10.4.19-MariaDB-1:10.4.19+maria~focal'.  SQL version

Comment: @RoMEoMusTDiE yes exactly

Comment: *@PARM is a parameter* This is syntax error. The function parameter is local variable, not user-defined one, and its name cannot start from `@` char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION GetFIYear (parameter DATE)
RETURNS DATE
RETURN CONCAT(YEAR(parameter - INTERVAL 6 MONTH), '-06-30');
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=01edd6d3c5880e3bc62f044ba607c216)

During the function call the `parameter` must be literal, column name or expression. Its value must be valid for DATE or DATETIME value (for example, if the value is VARCHAR column then its value must contain valid datetime literal). See [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Date and Time Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html). UNIX TIMESTAMP (numeric) value is not valid and must be converted with `FROM_UNIXTIME()`.

If the value provided to the function is not valid datetime one and current SQL Server mode is strict then the error is generated. If the value is not valid but the mode is not strict then the function returns NULL and the warning is generated.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a solution with  Stored Function/Procedure to query large datasets which is a tedious task to start with.. Thanks for your answer, appreciate it